# Cast to Array failed when insertind data to mongodb via express.sj

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I am making a webiste using MERN stack, I've managed to insert data from forms in react front end to mongodb but when I made a new form I get a cast to array failed error. I've tried casting to another array in my mongroose model and that worked just fine. the system is a mock online bank, never to be used in any production enviournment

My model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Creates the needed schema
let userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  balance: Number,
  address: String,
  ssn: Number,
  bankNumber: Number,
  cards: [
    {
      type: String, // Visa eller Mastercard
      cardNumber: Number,
      cvc: Number,
      expirationDate: Number,
      pin: Number,
      status: Boolean,
      dailyLimit: '9900'
    }
  ],
  whitdrawal: [
    {
      amount: Number,
      date: Date, // Skriv auto date logikk
      reason: String
    }
  ]
});
// Inserts
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  this.updated_at = currentDate;
  this.date = currentDate;
  if (!this.created_at) this.created_at = currentDate;

  next();
});

// Creates model for schema
const AtmUser = mongoose.model('AtmUser', userSchema);

// Export so it is available for the rest of the application
module.exports = AtmUser;
```

Express method for saving this data, data is sent from front end and visible in terminal error message

```
app.post('/api/newUser', function(req) {
  const newUser = AtmUser({
    name: req.body.name, 
    balance: req.body.balance, 
    address: req.body.address,
    ssn: req.body.ssn, 
    bankNumber: req.body.bankNumber,
    cards: [
      { 
        type: req.body.type, // Visa eller Mastercard
        cardNumber: req.body.cardNumber,
        cvc: req.body.cvc,
        expirationDate: req.body.expirationDate,
        pin: req.body.pin,
      }
    ],
  });

  newUser.save(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err; 
    console.log('A new user has been made')
  })
})
```

When trying to cast to whitdrawal arary instead of cards array everything works as expected, part of the erorr message I get in terminal

```
events.js:167
[0]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[0]       ^
[0] ValidationError: AtmUser validation failed: cards: Cast to Array failed for value "[ { type: '234234234' } ]" at path "cards"
[0]     at new ValidationError (/Users/andreas/Documents/prosjekt/atm/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:30:11)
```

I've been trying to spot the error for a few hours but just cannot find it, thank you for all replies! I'd be happy to post more of the code or the entire error message if that would help

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I found the answer, it turns out that type is a reserved word, changing it to formType og Type solved the issue in my model.

Corrected model:

```
app.post('/api/newUser', function(req) {
  const newUser = AtmUser({
    name: req.body.name, 
    balance: req.body.balance, 
    address: req.body.address,
    ssn: req.body.ssn, 
    bankNumber: req.body.bankNumber,
    cards: [
      { 
        formType: req.body.type, // Visa eller Mastercard
        cardNumber: req.body.cardNumber,
        cvc: req.body.cvc,
        expirationDate: req.body.expirationDate,
        pin: req.body.pin,
      }
    ],
  });

  newUser.save(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err; 
    console.log('A new user has been made')
  })
})
```